# angular-utils-pagination with rails sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, pagination, sprockets

`angular-utils-pagination` depends on `dirPagination.tpl.html` for the pagination controls. I used bower to install it in bower_components. So the tree structure is

```
vendor
└── assets
    ├── bower_components
        ├── angular-utils-pagination
        ├── README.md
        ├── bower.json
        ├── dirPagination.js
        └── dirPagination.tpl.html
```

config/application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor','assets','bower_components')

config.assets.precompile << %r(.*.(?:eot|svg|ttf|woff|html)$)
```

when I deploy the app to production, asset precompile kicks in and copies the `dirPagination.tpl.html` to `public/assets/angular-utils-pagination/dirPagination.tpl-8832242a2286b6a5e4623e6597069175.html`. The app gives a 404 when angular tries to include the file.

How can I tell angular from where to access this file?

Answer (score 0):

i use the following directive

```
 <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" **template-url="Templates\dirPagination.tpl.html"**>
```

and its work fine for me